# Extracting a .PNG from .EXE?

Tags: php, windows, icons

I have always thought how to extract an image from the icon of a .exe window file.
Is there an *easy* way to do it maybe with GD?

I think the step would be:

- extract .ico from .exe
- convert .ico in .PNG

Comment: Icons are generally very small graphics designed to show something clearly. This means they usually contain the type of image that JPEG is not designed to handle. You almost certainly want to rethink and use PNG instead.

Comment: Certainly more than a notion. The easiest way I see would be to call up a program that can do it for you like ResHacker instead of trying to find a function or a pear library that can do it for you. Nevertheless, interesting question.

Comment: Maybe it's possibile.. let's wait :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An icon is a [fairly complex beast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)). Converting to a PNG will not be easy, because:

- There can be several icons inside a single .exe;
- There can be several images inside a single icon, with different sizes and color depths;
- The images can be compressed in several ways;
- The images have bitmasks (making such effects as inverting background colors possible), which have no equivalent in PNG.

As far as I'm aware GD does not support icon format. Imagemagick seems to, maybe you can use that. Otherwise you might need to write your own icon extractor.

Comment: +1 No idea why someone down-voted! ImageMagick will do the job very nicely.

Comment: @David: I didn't, but it was possibly because -- although this answer covers the problems very well -- it doesn't actually offer a firm solution.

Comment: @Tomalak It's mean to down-vote somebody because they don't hold your hand all the way and write the code for you!!  Just my opinion.

Comment: @David: I agree. As I said, I didn't down-vote it. That said, this is not a resource to be populated with "JFGI!"; it's a resource to collect programming knowledge. The best SO answers are thorough, reasoned, and present a well-rounded solution with code examples. I can see why someone might have down-voted it if they were a little stricter than you or I.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Problem wouldn't be to convert from ico to png, the real problem (imo) is early: how to extract that ico form exe.. I don't think imagemagick can do that

Comment: @yes123 - Then you need some kind of resource tool... I suppose there should be a lot of command-line tools out there, but most will be for windows. Here, the first result in google is already what you need: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iconsext.html

Comment: @vilx: i need it on linux, i am on LAMP

Comment: and it must be command-line compatbile since i need it in an automated routine

Comment: @yes123 - That's what I was afraid of. That could get difficult. I'm afraid you'll have to do a lot of googling. There HAS to be something out there. :P Google for "resource extract", because icons are "resources" that can be embedded in an EXE file (that's the official term, and there are other resources besides icons too).